# Namecoin name_new fee for already taken

Tags: namecoin, domain-registering

I'm very new to Namecoin and tried to to register a domain with `name_new d/<name>`. I received the tx and rand response which seemed normal. Later (after 12+ blocks) when I did `firstupdate` and it responded with an error (using windows and I think I had escape issues):

```
error: {"code":-1,"message":"name_firstupdate <name> <rand> [<tx>] <value>\nPerf
orm a first update after a name_new reservation.\nNote that the first update wil
l go into a block 12 blocks after the name_new, at the soonest."}
```

So I corrected the escape issues and reissued `firstupdate`:

```
error: {"code":-1,"message":"this name is already active"}
```

And then thinking maybe the original `firstupdate` took, escape issues and all, I tried an `update`:

```
error: {"code":-1,"message":"this coin is not in your wallet"}
```

I then did what I should have done first and [looked up the domain name](http://dot-bit.org/tools/domainSearch.php) and found it exists and will expire in 188 days.

So... my questions are:

1) Why did the name_new not inform me it was taken? The [Wiki](http://dot-bit.org/HowToRegisterAndConfigureBitDomains) implies using name_new checks for existance:

> Or check if your domain if free with the command line (the command
>   line don't do the conversion) :
>
> ```
> ./namecoind name_new d/<name>
> ```

2) Does the .01 fee for `name_new` just disappear?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little bit late, but for everybody who is interested, the easy command to check if a name exists is simply:

```
> ./namecoind name_show d/<name>
```

It will return some informations should the name already be registered, or it will return

```
error: {"code":-4,"message":"failed to read from name DB"}
```

if the name doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

Just use namecoin-qt
This does everything automatically.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.